# DELETE FROM articles WHERE article_id = ? LIMIT?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Doctrine2 with Symfony :

```
$this->get('database_connection')->executeUpdate("DELETE FROM articles 
        WHERE article_id = :article_id 
        LIMIT :quantity", 
    array(
       'article_id' => 1,
       'quantity'   => 2
));
```

I get the error :

> An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM articles 
>   WHERE article_id = ? LIMIT ?' with params [1, 2]: SQLSTATE[42000]:
>
> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ''2'' at line 3

How can i pass a parameter to the LIMIT clause ?

I prefer not to use `bindValue` function but `executeUpdate` function instead.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding how your database is setup, but shouldn't article ID be a unique number? And If so, do you really need the Limit?

Comment: article_id is not unique. So yes, I need the limit.

Comment: Would it not be wise to use some form of ordering such as on a date column if you plan to delete a specific number of rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `executeUpdate` unlike `setParameter` **does NOT** automatically infers which type you are setting as value, and threats all params as strings. Therefore, you should explicitly set params as integers.

```
$this->get('database_connection')->executeUpdate("DELETE FROM articles 
        WHERE article_id = :article_id 
        LIMIT :quantity", 
    array(
       'article_id' => 1,
       'quantity'   => 2)
    array(
        \PDO::PARAM_INT,
        \PDO::PARAM_INT
    )
);
```

Answer (score -2):

you can still use execute update with the following syntax, this will insert the first value into article then the second into limit. not tested but should work

```
$this->get('database_connection')->executeUpdate("DELETE FROM articles 
        WHERE article_id = ?
        LIMIT ?, 
    array(1,2)
);
```

Comment: "Not tested" is a good sign that this won't work. The code even yields a syntax error. Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it